# How to create a sub-menu scrollable dropdown using semantic-ui?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

In the guide it says it is not possible to do it by using a standard method: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#scrolling

However, has anyone manage to do it?

In the moment you make a sub-menu drop-down scrollable, the triangle that points the drop-down button, disappears, as the overflow changes from visible to auto.

From this:

[image]

Goes to this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the framework says you can't do it, you can't do it. However, there are always work-arounds.

http://jsfiddle.net/cronq539/

Note: ***the following snippet won't work when you click "run"***, because stack overflow does not allow sufficient height in the demo to display the popup in view. Go to the jsfiddle link above to see it work.

```js
$('.ui.dropdown').popup({
  popup: $('.ui.popup'),
  on: 'click'
});

$('.ui.menu .item').on('click', function() {
  $('.ui.dropdown').click();
  alert(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```css
.ui.popup.fitted {
  padding: 0px;
}
.ui.popup.fitted > .ui.menu {
  border: none;
}
.ui.menu.scrolling {
  max-height: 20.57142857rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.11.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui floating primary labeled icon top right pointing dropdown button">
  <i class="add user icon"></i>
  <span class="text">1</span>
</div>
<div class="ui fitted popup">
 <div class="ui vertical scrolling menu">
    <a class="item">Choice 1</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 2</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 3</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 4</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 5</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 6</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 7</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 8</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 9</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 10</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 11</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 12</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 13</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 14</a>
    <a class="item">Choice 15</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing mate :)